# What exactly happens when I exec apt-get upgrade?

Tags: apt

What happens with package when I upgrade rather than removing and reinstalling? What is the real difference between the two? How will the results differ?

Are following two options equal (by package *preinst*/*postint*/*prerm*/*postrm* steps) ?

```
apt-get update
apt-get remove <packagename>
apt-get install <packagename>
```

and

```
apt-get update
apt-get install --only-upgrade <packagename>
```

Can you handle upgrade command specially? Is it possible to make a handler for upgrade instead of deleting and installing?

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Comment: Wen you remove package:

    *dpkg -r <packagename>*

Its including few steps, such as calling a prerm/postrm script.

When you executing 

    *dpkg -i <packagename>*

The preinst/postint scripts from .deb package will calling.

What scripts will calling if I try to exec

    apt-get install --only-upgrade <packagename>

?

Comment: Your comment is clearer than your question. I recommend editing your question to make it clearer.

Comment: I'm not sure you got it right. I'm looking for a difference between *apt-get remove <packagename> && apt-get install <packagename>* and *apt-get install --upgrade-only <packagename>*

Comment: If you want your question answered, you need to ask it more clearly. I answered based on my (possibly incorrrect) understanding of what you were asking. Please edit your question to make it clearer.

Comment: question updated

Comment: Ok, your question is clearer now. However, I still don't understand what you mean by "is it possible to make a handler for upgrade instead of deleting and installing?" What do you mean by a handler?

Comment: I want to handle upgrade command and ask addition confirm before my package will be removed. In other way user may stop application unexpectedly by using apt-get upgrade.

Comment: The Debian wiki has some handy flowcharts that explain what scripts are called in what order when you install, remove or update a package: https://wiki.debian.org/MaintainerScripts

Comment: And, if I understand your concerns correctly: Upgrading a package will not put it in the same state as removing it during any step of the process (again, see the flowcharts). When a service needs to be restarted for the upgrade, the package maintainer will usually take care to do so with as little downtime as possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Upgrading a package is not the same thing as removing and then installing it. Upgrading takes care to minimize the time during which the package isn't fully operational, whereas removing then installing leaves a window during which none of the package's files are present. Apart from that, they don't run the same maintainer scripts: upgrading runs the maintainer scripts (old `prerm`, new `preinst`, old `postrm`, new `postinst`) with the `upgrade` action, whereas removing then reinstalling runs old `prerm remove`, old `postrm remove`, new `preinst install`, new `postinst configure`. See the [Debian policy manual](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-maintainerscripts.html#s-mscriptsinstact) for details, or the [wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/MaintainerScripts) for diagrams.

If you're making deb packages and you want to do something special on an upgrade, do it for the `upgrade` action of the relevant maintainer script (usually `postinst` to upgrade configuration files and restart daemons).

Comment: That's exactly what I have searched. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

To answer your question, `dpkg` calls the same scripts (on a per package basis) whether you are using `--only-upgrade` with `apt` or not. It makes no difference. `--only-upgrade` only affects which packages `apt` operates on. As the man page says:

> ```
> --only-upgrade
>        Do not install new packages; when used in conjunction with 
>        install, only-upgrade will install upgrades for already 
>        installed packages only and ignore requests to install new 
>        packages. Configuration Item: APT::Get::Only-Upgrade.
> ```

When `dpkg` removes a package, the corresponding prerm/postrm scripts of that package are called. When `dpkg` installs a package, the corresponding preinst/postint scripts are called. And again, this is all run by `dpkg`. `apt` operates at a higher level.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. The question is about the difference between upgrading vs removing + installing a package; it is **not** about the difference between installing with or without the --only-upgrade option. See the [accepted answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/218733/54670) for what the question is looking for.

Answer (score 1):

"upgrade" means upgrade all packages which have newer versions available in the configured package repositories than the ones which you currently have installed.

"install" means add a particular package (with the latest available version), or upgrade to that version if an earlier version of the package is already installed.

Removing an installed package, before running install to upgrade it, is unnecessary, and might have unpleasant side effects.

It is good practice to run "upgrade" regularly, to get security updates for all packages you have installed.

Comment: The question is about upgrade package steps, which will run after apt-get install --only-upgrade <packagename>.
Does it include only *prerm/postrm*, *preinst/postinst* steps?

Comment: This does not answer the question.